# How to remove DEBUG logging from the Amazon EC2 client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2

I have the following simple code

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
DescribeInstancesResult response = ec2.describeInstances(request);
```

While running this code I see the multiline debug output. I show only the beginning below.  How to remove this output?

```
14:03:29.877 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient - Internal logging successfully configured to commons logger: true
14:03:38.129 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics - Admin mbean registered under com.amazonaws.management:type=AwsSdkMetrics
14:03:38.480 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain - Unable to load credentials from EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
14:03:38.482 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain - Unable to load credentials from SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey)
14:03:38.580 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain - Loading credentials from com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@7fb9f71f
14:03:38.786 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Sending Request: POST https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com / Parameters: ({"Action":["DescribeInstances"],"Version":["2016-11-15"]}Headers: (User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.11.135 Mac_OS_X/10.12.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.144-b01/1.8.0_144, amz-sdk-invocation-id: 0a1303b3-16c0-b140-8d9b-b2e22dc685b1, ) 
14:03:40.160 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer - AWS4 Canonical Request: '"POST /

 amz-sdk-invocation-id:0a1303b3-16c0-b140-8d9b-b2e22dc685b1
 amz-sdk-retry:0/0/500
 host:ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 user-agent:aws-sdk-java/1.11.135 Mac_OS_X/10.12.6 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.144-b01/1.8.0_144
 x-amz-date:20171113T190338Z
```

Answer (score 2):

**Log4j Assumption**

Under the assumption your application's logging system is configured via a property file like `log4j.properties` present at the base of your Java classpath, you can reduce verbosity of the loggers by including the line

```
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=WARN
```

`WARN` or `ERROR` will guarantee you get the least amount of logs for the loggers inside the AWS SDK.

Should you wish to keep a more granular level of logging for a specific component of the AWS SDK, you can always override the level on a restricted scope (i.e. a subpackage of the `com.amazonaws`), e.g.

```
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws.request=INFO
```

**Logging frameworks supported by AWS Java SDK**

The AWS SDK documentation states "*Supported logging systems include the Java Logging Framework and Apache Log4j, among others*".
I refer you to [Logging AWS SDK for Java Calls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html) for further reference.

**Checking which logging framework is used by the test**

The Apache Commons logging library referenced from Gradle is an abstraction layer on top of logging libraries which provide actual implementations of loggers. It is not, in itself, the logging implementation used by your test. In the statement you provided, you are using the Java logging framework ( `java.util.Logger` a.k.a JUL). But is it really the logging implementation your test uses?

A quick check you could do to verify if log4j is on your test's classpath is to add the VM argument `-Dlog4j.debug=true` and launch your test. If log4j is on your classpath you will see some output from the library printed on the console.

You could also check the *runtime* classpath of your test, because there may be transitive dependencies (as opposed to direct) to logging libraries, which may not be visible from the list of compile-time dependencies.

One last resort possibility could be to put a breakpoint [there](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2bf51225197a1a87dc950bb9b9f5761a914900bf/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.java#L79) and debug to see which logger is used from the SDK itself (this code is called in your test because it is shown in the logs you provided).

Comment: what you suggest is not a Java code.  How do you insert this into a Java code?

Comment: It depends on the logging library - which one do you use?

Comment: In gradle dependencies I see commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2

Comment: ok, I think the first logger this library will try to use is log4j's. Does the following compile: `Configurator.setLevel("com.amazonaws", Level.WARN)`?

Comment: This is compiled but does not help: java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.amazonaws").setLevel(Level.WARNING);

Comment: @AlexNarinsky - you _do not_ want to hardcode logger settings. You should always configure logging using an appropriate config file that is external to the application. But first, you need to learn what logging framework you're using and how to configure it.

Comment: @kdgregory, it is a short JUNIT test file, therefore I am doing quick config in Java. Still, how to learn what framework is used by AWS?

Comment: @AlexNarinsky Updated the post with some comments on how to check which logging framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using spring boot and use aws client to get some secrets before bootstrap spring boot environment, but all secrets go to debug messages then I tried a lot of methods but this is the one works for me:

```
 LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) 
 LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
 loggerContext.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(Level.INFO);
 loggerContext.getLogger("com.amazonaws").setLevel(Level.INFO);
```